# how to determine if there's a null on the list item C#

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, nullable

A Quick Question

How can I determine if my whole list items has a null value for example like this item .

Note that my list is dynamic so i can't be like manually get the [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saHgz.png) on my code .

This is how I get the list

```
item.BList.Add(AllList.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault());
```

[image]

What I tried so far is this

```
 if(items.SelectedItem== null)
{
     item.BList.Add(AllList.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault());

     foreach (var dep in item.Blist)
     {    
          item.Blist.RemoveAll(item => dep == null);
     }
     return;
}
```

But won't delete instead crashes my app

Comment: I added more information sorry about that

Comment: You need the `.Any` method - `AllList.Any(x => x == null)`.

Comment: Could you explain sir because I'm a very new to linq how does .any will remove my null item list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Where()` clause with negation to get all not null values from the list.

```
item.Blist = item.Blist.Where(item => item != null);  //Now item.Blist contains all non null elements.
```

Your code will look like,

```
if(items.SelectedItem== null)
{
     item.BList.Add(AllList.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault());
     item.Blist = item.Blist.Where(item => item != null);

     return;
}
```

If you are looking for solution to check list contains any `null` value, then you can use `Any()`

```
var isNullValueExist = item.Blist.Any(x => x == null); //This will return boolean value based on predicate
```

Answer (score 0):

For Remove All You just have to do following things.

```
item.Blist.RemoveAll(item => item == null);
```

Overall it looks like

```
if(items.SelectedItem== null)
{
     item.BList.Add(AllList.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault());
     item.Blist.RemoveAll(item => item == null);

     return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove Items from a list while you are iterating through it (foreach) because it changes the order or elements and length of the list so the forach loop cannot track the indexes correctly.

If you are trying to remove null elements from the list

```
if(items.SelectedItem== null)
{
     item.BList.Add(AllList.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault());
     item.Blist.RemoveAll(i => i == null); // You donn't have to iterate the list to do this

     foreach (var dep in item.Blist)
     {    
          // Do whatever you want with your items or just remove the forach loop altogether
          // item.Blist.RemoveAll(item => dep == null); // don't have to do this here
     }
     return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're creating your own problem with this line:

```
item.BList.Add(AllList.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault());
```

If the `.Where(x => x.Id == id)` doesn't match then you are adding `null` to the `item.BList` - which you then want to remove. You should just avoid adding it in the first place.

You could do that like this:

```
var element = AllList.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
if (element != null)
{
    item.BList.Add(element);
}
```

Or, assuming `item.BList` is a `List<T>`, like this:

```
item.BList.AddRange(AllList.Where(x => x.Id == id).Take(1));
```